# How to find possible viral subsequences in a Eukaryote genome?

Tags: blast, blastn

I have an assembly of an algae and want to find if it has anything analogous to endogenous retroviruses' subsequences in its DNA.

My guess is I should manually blastn all subsequences until I find (or not something) that could have come from a virus.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it your analysis any different to the detection of horizontal gene transfer? (Or at least I would search for this keywords for an answer)

Comment: you can try with kraken: https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb-2014-15-3-r46

Answer (score 2):

Your guess sounds reasonable to me but you should consider using [KRAKEN2](https://github.com/DerrickWood/kraken2/wiki/Manual). You can create your custom database (you would have done it with makeblastdb anyway) and kraken will check k-mers against the database to find homologous sequences.

Comment: I don't feel Kraken is good for this task. Kraken taxonomically classifies each sequence, while the signature of integrated viral DNA will be a single sequence with both host and virus parts

Comment: @Chris_Rands. Preparing your custom dataset with only viral genome and with the right k-length for the kmer analysis is the only method I know of existance today. You can use manually blastn (honestly, I do this myself if it's not for publication) or let the job to a well developed (and fast) software out-there. Please, let me know if you think of a better or potentially better solution!

Comment: Your suggestion might be fine for detecting viruses in general, but not integrated viruses specifically- this requires a fundamentally different approach because you are looking for chimeric reads

Comment: @Chris_Rands chimeric reads could be found using shorter kmers (at the expense of dropping specificity). Do you know of any better or alternative solution?

Answer (score -1):

Searching directly for a reverse transcriptase may find recently incorporated retroviruses.